# Using 3.3V XBee with Arduino Pro Mini 5V Version

Tags: xbee, voltage-level, arduino-pro-mini

The Xbee requires a 3.3V power input and the Arduino Pro Mini (5V version) only provides a regulated 5V.

**Question:** What will be the simplest way to provide a 3.3V rail to the XBee from the Arduino Pro Mini?

If we use a voltage divider consisting of 2 resistors, the ratio should be 66/100, but how do we choose the resistor values?

If we choose a 3.3V voltage regulator, will the [STMicroelectronics L78L33ACZ](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000446.pdf) be suitable?

[image]

Between the voltage divider and voltage regulator, which is the preferred method? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: There is a second part to this - does the XBee talk to the Arduino? Connecting a 5v device to a 3.3v device requires a level shifter to protect and interface between the different voltage devices. While both power and IO can be interfaced using simple voltage divider resistors - personally I recommend regulating the 3.3v supply and using a simple MOSFET level shifter for IO. If you update the question for this, I can post a relevant circuit to accomplish both.

Comment: @RonJ. Yes XBee is communicating with Arduino. How can you use the MOSFET level shifter for IO? Will be great if I can have a look at your circuit :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you need a 5V Pro Mini? If not, then it would be much more appropriate to use a 3.3V Pro Mini in its place.

Answer (score 5):

This is part of a Fritzing circuit I used to control the x'mas tree lights (the relays and sensors have been snipped out) with an XBee. This circuit uses a 3.3v LDO you may have to change the capacitor values depending on your regulator specs. I chose to use a separate 5V regulator (not shown) but it will work off the Pro Mini's +5V power rail.

There are two FETs that do the actual level shifting, the bonus transistor allows you to reset the Arduino and thus gives you the ability to program it over the air via the XBee (beyond the scope of the question, but if you want to go wireless, go wireless all the way - do the Google for wireless programming over XBee if needed). Note the 0.1uF across the XBee power pins, I recommend this capacitor be placed as close to the XBee as possible to minimize noise (I solder it across the back of the XBee interface board).

[image]

Comment: In what ways can noise across the XBee's power inputs affect it?

Comment: @Nyxynyx I don't remember exactly where it was specified, may have been in the XBee datasheet. The XBee is after all a 2.4GHz transceiver, and electrical noise [could] [may] disrupt communications. A 3 cent disc capacitor certainly doesn't hurt things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a voltage regulator to get the supply voltage down to 3.3v.

For the Serial Lines, the best way forward is to use a good level convertor like https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11978 from sparkfun.

If you don't want to buy it, you can also make it using a couple of Mosfet's and resistors. Here's the [schematic](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Logic_Level_Converter.pdf) from Sparkfun.

Comment: Please do not link to external content.  When the URL become invalid, this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way**, as you ask, is probably a resitor-based [voltage divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider); its main drawback is the waste of energy in the resistors.

[image]

To calculate the "best" resistor values, you'll need to know the amount of **current** needed by the XBee module.

So you have:

- `Vin` = **5V**
- `Vout` = **3.3V**
- `Iout` = to be determined (check XBee spec sheet for that)

Then you have to resolve the following equations to calculate the resistor values you shall use:

```
R1 = R2 x (Vin - Vout) / Vout
Iout = (Vin - Vout) / R1 - Vout / R2
```

These equations simply come from applying Ohm's law and Kirchhoff's circuit laws.

This [site calculates the ideal resistor values](http://www.power-io.com/library/appnotes/voltage-divider.htm) for you.

For `Iout` = **100mA**, it gives the following values:

- `R1 = 17 Ohm`
- `R2 = 33 Ohm`

Another **simple way** is to use a **3.3V zener diode** if you have one on hand. You can google for good circuit examples.